# How to render ng-template dynamically with Template Reference in Angular

Tags: html, angular, forms, ng-template, ng-container

I tried the example in this question [Dynamic ngTemplateOutlet value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43577481/dynamic-ngtemplateoutlet-value) but still, no success.

I want to dynamically display an `ng-template` form based on the option selected by the user.

I have defined global variables and 3 forms with their Template References in my component.ts

```
@ViewChild('formA', {static: false}) formAref: TemplateRef<any>;
formA = new UserForm('formA', 'Mus Mauris Form', this.formAref);

@ViewChild('formB', {static: true}) formBref: TemplateRef<any>;
formB = new UserForm('formB', 'Vitae Purus Faucibus Form ', this.formBref);

@ViewChild('formC', {static: true}) formCref: TemplateRef<any>;
formC = new UserForm('formC', 'Aliquet Nec Form', this.formCref);


selectedForm: TemplateRef<any>;
totalForms: UserForm[] = [];
```

where UserForm is defined as

```
interface UserFormInterface {
  id: string;
  display: boolean;
  submitFunc: Function;
}

class UserForm implements UserFormInterface {
  id: string;
  form_name: string;
  display: boolean;
  submitFunc: Function;
  reference: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor(id: string, form_name: string, reference: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.id = id;
    this.form_name = form_name;
    this.reference = reference;
  }
}
```

In my HTML template I have the following

```
<div id="inner-form-dashboard" class="row">
      <div id="form-list" class="col-4">
          <div
               *ngFor="let form of totalForms" 
              class="form-item d-flex flex-column justify-content-around align-items-center">
              <div class="form-link" (click)="showForm(form)">{{form.form_name}}</div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="form-container" class="col-8 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
          <div *ngFor="let form of totalForms">
              <ng-container *ngIf="form.display" style="display: block;">
                {{form.id}}
                  <div
                      *ngTemplateOutlet='selectedForm'>
                  </div>
              </ng-container>
          </div>  
      </div>
</div>

<ng-template #formA>
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example textarea</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
    </form>
</ng-template>
```

The first column `col-4` will determine which form to display on the second column `col-8` based on which item is clicked on the left.

[image]

When I click on the left item, I can see that the `form.id` is displayed on the right side, meaning that the selection of the forms and the `ngFor` are working properly, however, the templates on line `*ngTemplateOutlet='selectedForm'>` are not displayed.

The functionality looks like this in my component

```
showForm(form: UserForm): void {
    this.totalForms.forEach(f => f.display = false);
    form.display = true;
    this.selectedForm = form.reference;
    console.log(form);
    console.log('selected', this.selectedForm);
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-34r1gw

https://angular-34r1gw.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of your issue is that you are attempting to use the template references too early. The earliest that `@ViewChild` properties with `{ static: true }` are available is in the [ngOnInit](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit) lifecycle hook:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.formA = new UserForm('formA', 'Mus Mauris Form', this.formAref);
  this.formB = new UserForm('formB', 'Vitae Purus Faucibus Form ', this.formBref);
  this.formC = new UserForm('formC', 'Aliquet Nec Form', this.formCref);
  this.totalForms.push(this.formA, this.formB, this.formC);
}
```

When using `{ static: false }`, then the earliest that the `@ViewChild` properties are available is in the [ngAfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) lifecycle hook.

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pq6wjg?file=src/app/app.component.ts)